# Advantages/Disadvantages of "Prior Career" in Character Generation

Tags: character-creation, system-agnostic

This could be considered related to - but definitely not the same as - [What are the advantages and disadvantages of develop in play (DIP) compared to develop at the start (DAS) character generation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-develop-in-play-dip-compared-to-d). For this question, I'm interested in focussing on the method and results of "Prior Career"-style generation, where you end up with a character that has a "partial backstory" and skills, vs. what I call, in my biased fashion, "Throw the kid in at the deep end"-style character generation, where you start with a character that may have certain aptitudes, but no actual skills to speak of.

I get that "deep end" character generation is likely to be faster, and that the idea is to play the game, not spend a session rolling up characters. I also get that you'll develop the skills in play. Why would this be considered advantageous, *aside* from the metareasons given? As near as I can tell, "Prior Career"-style generation is pretty much limited to the various incarnations of *Traveller*; why has this sort of chargen not been taken up by other systems/genres?

1st edit: I'm not looking at development of the *personality* of the character, as the DIP vs DAS dichotomy seems to emphasize; I'm looking at the contrast between mechanics.

2nd edit: After seeing the discussion that the unclearness seems to have prompted, I'd have to say that the question is ultimately less about advantages/disadvantages of a specific mechanic, and more about advantages/disadvantages of chargen that starts you with a skilled/experienced character vs. chargen that throws you into the game with no experience.

Comment: Is there a distinction between "DAS" and "Prior Career", definition-wise?

Comment: @godskook the difference is between fluff and crunch. DAS/DIP dichotomy is about how you develop your character's personality and how you roleplay them, but prior-career means a type of chargen system with rules that are used to define your character's background and modify your character's mechanical attributes and qualities.

Comment: You seem to be conflating two different issues, which is experienced vs inexperienced characters and strict vs freeform chargen. A prior-career chargen system is a specific way of doing strict character generation to create experienced characters and I would in fact argue that it is designed to speed up that process significantly. Freeform character generation of experienced characters is typically horrendously complicated and takes ages. I was writing a lengthy answer arguing against your premise but I figure maybe this is a misunderstanding that can be clarified before going to such lengths.

Comment: Would you include the life path system of Burning Wheel in your definition of "prior career" chargen?

Comment: Are you looking for (or even distinguishing between) character-as-stats and character-as-personality? A rules-heavy system like Traveller could produce a faceless, generic "served three terms in the navy, then four years as a merchant". A system as ephemeral as Roll For Shoes could well include a highly detailed personality.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  System-mechanic answers?  Player-approach perspectives outside of system or mechanics?  How subjective an answer are you looking for, and what is a good subjective answer in this case?

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely conflating a life path system with "a system where you start with skills."   Going to put this on hold to clarify exactly what you're trying to contrast with what here, the first answer is already confused on that point.

Comment: @Carcer - I'd like some clarification on the definitions of "strict" vs. "freeform" character generation; I'm not sure I can respond further to your comment lacking that clarification.

Comment: @SirTechSpec - After doing a bit of googling, I'd say that BW's Lifepath generation is probably closer to "prior career" than it is to "deep end".

Comment: @mxyzplk - It's more about the _mechanic_ metadiscussion than about the player creating a personality. Personality development, as far as I am concerned, happens to the extent and at the time the player chooses; it can't really be enforced at a particular time. Think of it this way: Given closely similar settings, why should I choose playing in that setting with a "prior career" or "lifepath" system vs. a "roll 'em up and toss 'em in at the deep end" system?

Comment: @JoelHarmon - See my comment to **mxyzplk**; from my point of view, personality is between the player, the character, and the group-as-a-whole, and doesn't have any necessary connection to the rules.

Comment: @Carcer - absent the clarification of "strict" vs "freeform", I will say that at least part of the question does involve the relative merits of experienced vs inexperienced, with another part - possibly unrelated and worth a separate question - being "gain skills in play" vs "don't gain...".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin despite best efforts I've yet to master posting while sleeping. A strict chargen system restricts the mechanical choice available to the player whereas a freeform one is open-ended. Your question is still bad because it still conflates experienced vs. inexperienced with this prior-career vs. not-so divide. A freeform chargen system which does not require you to specifically choose past career options can still be used to represent an experienced character; most RPG systems do not assume chars are total newbs with no skills to speak of, but your question implies that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, this is still all confused.  There's systems that use lifepath vs freeform generation.  There's systems that start you as an inexperienced character and there's ones that start you (or allow you to start as) a more experienced character. There's systems that give you unfettered choice (e.g. Point buy) and ones that constrain you (e.g. Class based).  All of these are unrelated axes. What specifically are you asking about and why?

Answer (score -1):

It is really a style choice.

However, there are some advantages to either DAS or DIP in certain situations.

**DIP:**  If you have new players and a complex system, DIP allows the players to add more complexity as the characters grow but starts them with a simplified rules set.  Also, it gives more of a sense of growing the character.  This style of play is good for those who like book series and wuxia novels.

**DAS:**  If you have a one off or short duration campaign, it is better to have characters that are already competent to pull it off.  Also, if the players have trouble coming up with a character's background, this can give them something to work with.

Comment: This is an answer to the linked theoretically non-duplicate.